# How to set navigation bar's back item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation bar, which is presented modally from another view controller so the back item is not shown,

I need to cross dissolve to the second view controller, and put a navigation bar on it without putting one on the first view controller, on the navigation bar of the second view controller the back button should look exactly like system back button.

Answer (score 1):

If you have navigation bar and you need custom back button, you can add it like this:

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back Title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(someMethod))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
```

And in your selector you can dismiss your current viewController or call some other back method

**EDIT**

If you need some custom animation with standart push transition style you can do next:

For example create viewController in storyboard with `SecondViewController` id

At your transition action method make some like this:

```
func showSecondViewController() {
    guard navigationController != nil else {
        return
    }
    guard let secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") else {
        return
    }
    navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: false)
    UIView.transitionWithView(navigationController!.view, duration: 1, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yeah this adds a button, but it's not like the system `< Back` style, it looks strange

Comment: @BrightFuture Show modally does not imply the presence of the standard back button. In this case, you need a button that simply closes the window

Comment: I need the cross dissolve animation by showing modally, if I use push, can I change the default animation?

Comment: @BrightFuture I edit the answer. Try do like this, maybe it will help you get the desired result

Comment: Should this method be put in `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: Actually I'm having a even stranger problem: I reset the segue to push, but now it still animates either cross dissolve or cover vertical, and the back button is still not shown

Comment: @BrightFuture In this case, you do not need to make the segue. You need create `viewController` in storyboard with `Storyboard ID` and in place you need to push new viewController (button action or selectRowAtIndexPath methot) you call `showSecondViewController` function

Comment: This does seem to be a good solution :) but I can't hide the top bar on the first view controller

Comment: They'll hide altogether

Comment: @BrightFuture I no longer understand what you want to do. If you want to hide navigation bar on the first controller and show on the second just use the first variant of the answer and make a cross icon to close it:) Or add bar programmly when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The back item would appear automatically when you push a ViewController. When you present it modally you would do it outside the initial navigation controller, therefore it's navigation would get hidden by the new one.

Edition with the proposed solution: Embed the first UIViewController in a UINavigationViewController and push the second instead of presenting it modally.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a solution, maybe you should just comment?

Comment: Now it's a solution. The back button is a control belonging to a navigation controller, if you wont use the navigation then would have to re-create the back button by yourself.

Comment: Yeah it is a solution but I need the cross dissolve animation by presenting modally

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/) WWDC vide can help you out with this.